# Error handling for timer functions

Tags: matlab, error-handling, timer

I'm trying to handle errors that occur in some of my [`timer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer.html) functions (`TimerFcn`, `StopFcn`, ...). My problem is that I need to handle the errors *outside* of the actual callbacks. However, the following does *not* work:

```
callback = @(~, ~) error('Oops.');
try
    t = timer('TimerFcn', callback);
    start(t);
catch e
    fprintf('Caught exception: %s\n', e.message);
end
```

The output is:

```
Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-5' 

Oops.
```

I do understand why the above code does not work (after all, the idea of timers is to execute asynchronously). However I haven't found any other official way to achieve my goal (e.g. a global error handler that I could hook into).

The only workaround I've found so far is to shadow `error`:

```
oldError = @error;
errors = {};
error =  @(varargin) assignin('base', 'errors', [evalin('base', 'errors'), {varargin}]);
callback = @(~, ~) error('Oops.');
t = timer('TimerFcn', callback);
start(t);
wait(t);
```

The error is now stored in `errors`. However, this approach has a lot of problems: when to restore the original `error` function? How to deal with errors raised by code other than the timer functions? ...

Hence: **How can I handle errors in timer functions in a clean and reliable way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use the `ErrorFcn` property of the timer object.

A simple example:

```
>> tcallback = @(~, ~) error('Oops.');
>> ecallback = @(~, ~) disp('Caught error');
>> t = timer('TimerFcn', tcallback, 'ErrorFcn', ecallback);
>> start(t)
Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-2' 

Oops.


Caught error
```

You can obviously make your error handling more robust than that, but it takes care of the asynchronous nature of `timer` errors. The input arguments to the `ErrorFcn` (if you don't suppress them as in the above example) provide information about the error that was thrown, so you can handle them specifically.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for error thrown in the timer's `StopFcn`. I need to handle errors in any of the timer's callbacks (ideally even in `ErrorFcn`). Any ideas?

Comment: In addition, the error is still displayed. This is not acceptable, since it will make users think that there's a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what difficulty you're having in catching errors thrown by the `StopFcn` - it works for me. I don't believe there's a documented way to suppress displaying the error message, but if you are willing to edit the MATLAB source code you could comment out lines 42-45 of `toolbox\matlab\iofun\@timer\timercb.m`, which is what does the displaying. To avoid editing source, you could potentially make your own timer class that overloaded `timercb` with just that small modification, but it might be a pain as `timercb` calls private functions.

Comment: You're right, the problem with `StopFcn` was a mistake on my side. Editing the source is not possible (code will be shipped to customers). Thanks for the idea of overloading `timercb`, that might work.